# Acer aspire e1 wifi network disconnecting!

Tags: realtek

The Realtek 8723be disconnects the WIFI network after very little time.

*Where I can find the right driver?*

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Answer (score 1):

you can find the driver [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new).

To solve this problem try first to update your kernel version.

If this doesn't solve your problem then try to install the new driver.

Comment: thanks for driver! But i am first time user ubuntu! i update and upgradw kernel! But wifi disconnecting! how to install this driver from link?

Comment: @Raimonds Raimo use a different computer and transfer it via flash drive or your phone....DO NOT try to update kernel with spotty wifi....also have you ever thought about plugging the computer in directly to the router (Wired connection)? I downloaded the update for my computer and finally have reliable WiFi!

Comment: YES! cable network working. and i was made update and upgrade. who can tell me how to install this driver on ubuntu? https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new